# OneToMany count attribute

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have two entities, post and like, post has a OneToMany to like.

**Post Class**

```
   /**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Mag\MyBundle\Entity\PostRepository")
     */
    class Post {
//...

/**
 *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Mag\MyBundle\Entity\LikePost",mappedBy="post")
 *
 */
private $likes;
private $countLikes; 

//...
}
```

**Like Class**

```
/**
 * LikePost
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class LikePost
{
//...

  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mag\MyBundle\Entity\Post",cascade={"persist"},inversedBy="likes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $post ;
    //...
}
```

I want to get the count of likes in posts.
i tried in the PostRepository

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
       $query = $qb
                ->addSelect($qb->expr()->count('l'))
                ->leftJoin('p.likes', 'l')
                ->groupBy('p.id')
                ->orderBy('p.datePost', 'DESC')
                ->setFirstResult(($page - 1) * $count)
                ->setMaxResults($count)
                ->getQuery();
```

but it give an array of the two selection query.
How can i store the result of "->addSelect($qb->expr()->count('l'))" in the "$countLikes" attribute in post object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to write **custom hydration driver** which interprets the results but I haven't done anything like that yet.

Can you do it manually?

```
$query = $qb
    ->addSelect($qb->expr()->count('l'))
    ->leftJoin('p.likes', 'l')
    ->groupBy('p.id')
    ->orderBy('p.datePost', 'DESC')
    ->setFirstResult(($page - 1) * $count)
    ->setMaxResults($count)
    ->getQuery();

$result = $query->getResult();
$actualResult = array();

foreach ( $result as $r ){
    // assuming that object is at position `0` and like count at position `1`
    $r[0]->setCountLikes(intval($r[1]));

    $actualResult[] = $r[0];
}

return $actualResult;
```

Comment: it work, but this it isn't more greedy if there are a huge of queries ?

Comment: I think you should be ok, since the `COUNT` is calculated on `DBMS` side, so no additional queries will be fired. Also, I assume that `$count` is relatively small, maybe 50-100 max? That's the number of iterations, but `PHP` should handle that pretty fast.

Comment: another question please, how I can make a count with the where clause ? and thank you very much

Comment: Does `$qb->andWhere("COUNT(p.likes) > :count")` work? If not, try `$qb->addSelect("COUNT(p.likes) as likeCount")->andWhere("likeCount > :count")`

Comment: no, i want to get the count of specified likes, for example : `select count(p.likes) where p.likes.date = '2015-01-30' `

Comment: Why not just `SELECT COUNT(lp) FROM LikePost lp WHERE lp.date = '2015-01-30'`?

Comment: I looking for the most efficient way